# visibility attribute value is not rendering from product collection in magento 2

Tags: magento2, backend, product-collection, custom-attributes, resource-model

We need to display the visibility of the product in category page, but currently we are not able to fetch its value from product object.

We tried with `$_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();`

It is not working,we have **Magento ver. 2.2.5**.

Comment: did @Bare Feet solution worked for you ?

Answer (score 1):

NOT TESTED

Try this:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getAttributeCode(), 'attribute_code'); ?>
```